# Application of Bell Number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is difference between Bell number and stirling number of 2nd kind?
If we want to find number of equivalence class of a set, then bell number applicable? Why blindly should we say bell number applicable there? Finding partition of set we can also use it, right?

Comment: $B(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k)$.

Comment: Read [OEIS sequence A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110) or Wikipedia [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) for more information